# Jest Node.js Not able to call beforeAll and afterAll properly using separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, serverless-framework

I have defined `beforAll` and `afterAll` in a separate file `bootstrap.js` but I am not able to do integration testing. I am using serverless stack. I took help from github but that example was written in mocha so I tried to transform it to jest.

`bootstrap.js`

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    console.log('[Tests Bootstrap] Start');

    await startSlsOffline((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        console.log('[Tests Bootstrap] Done');
    });
}, 30000);

afterAll(async () => {
    console.log('[Tests Teardown] Start');

    await stopSlsOffline();

    console.log('[Tests Teardown] Done');
});
```

`handler.test.js`

```
describe('get Endpoints', () => {
    const server = request(`http://localhost:3005`);
    test('should run get example', async () => {
        const res = await server.get('/example');
        console.log('res', res.body);
    });
});
```

My jest configuration is

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    bail: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'output/coverage/jest',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [ './bootstrap.js' ]
};
```

The output I get is

```
> jest --config test/jest.config.js

 FAIL  test/handler.test.js
  get Endpoints
    ✕ should run get example (38ms)

  ● get Endpoints › should run get example

    connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3005



  console.log test/bootstrap.js:6
    [Tests Bootstrap] Start

  console.log test/bootstrap.js:30
    Serverless: Offline started with PID : 5587 and PORT: 3005

  console.log test/bootstrap.js:18
    [Tests Teardown] Start

  console.log test/bootstrap.js:47
    Serverless Offline stopped

  console.log test/bootstrap.js:22
    [Tests Teardown] Done

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.825s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using this config with help of 1st answer using `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown`.

Read more here - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string

`bootstrap.js`

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

let slsOfflineProcess;

module.exports = async () => {
    console.log('[Tests Bootstrap] Start');
    await startSlsOffline().catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
        return;
    });
    global.__SERVERD__ = slsOfflineProcess;
};

function startSlsOffline() {
    slsOfflineProcess = slsOfflineProcess = spawn('sls', [ 'offline', 'start', '--port', 3005 ]);

    return finishLoading();
}

const finishLoading = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        slsOfflineProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            if (data.includes('Serverless: Offline [HTTP] listening on')) {
                console.log(data.toString().trim());
                console.log(`Serverless: Offline started with PID : ${slsOfflineProcess.pid}`);
                resolve('ok');
            }

            if (data.includes('address already in use')) {
                reject(data.toString().trim());
            }
        });

        slsOfflineProcess.stderr.on('data', (errData) => {
            console.log(`Error starting Serverless Offline:\n${errData}`);
            reject(errData);
        });
    });
```

```
teardown.js
```

```
module.exports = async function() {
    let slsOfflineProcess = global.__SERVERD__;
    slsOfflineProcess.stdin.write('q\n');
    slsOfflineProcess.stdin.pause();
    await slsOfflineProcess.kill('SIGINT');
    console.log('Serverless Offline stopped');
};
```

Find a sample on this link here: https://github.com/bilalsha/sls-test-jest

P.S `globalTeardown` do not works if test fails. I will post solution once I have it.

Answer (score 1):

The global setup doesn't work the way you are expecting it to work. If you see the logs, your beforeAll logs are coming after your test executes. You should use different way to setup and teadown. Jest has concept of `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` and I guess that fits better in your case. As part of this you can start and stop your server. The config will look like this

Read more here - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    bail: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'output/coverage/jest',
    globalSetup: "./bootstrap.js",
    globalTeardown: "./bootstrap.js"
};
```

And your bootstrap will looks like this

```
const { spawn} = require('child_process');

let slsOfflineProcess;

module.exports = async () => {
    console.log('[Tests Bootstrap] Start');
    await startSlsOffline((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        console.log('[Tests Bootstrap] Done');
    });
}

const startSlsOffline = (done) => {
    if (slsOfflineProcess) {
        slsOfflineProcess.kill('SIGINT');
        console.log('Serverless Offline stopped');
        done();
    }

    slsOfflineProcess = spawn('sls', [ 'offline', 'start', '--port', 3005 ]);

    console.log(`Serverless: Offline started with PID : ${slsOfflineProcess.pid} and PORT: 3005`);

    slsOfflineProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        if (data.includes('Offline listening on')) {
            console.log(data.toString().trim());
            done();
        }
    });

    slsOfflineProcess.stderr.on('data', (errData) => {
        console.log(`Error starting Serverless Offline:\n${errData}`);
        done(errData);
    });
};
```

Comment: when i try to use promise I get this issue: ```Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.```

Comment: Do you need that timeout? It not, you can remove it else you will need to override the test’s default timeout to be more than that value

Comment: I have pushed this to https://github.com/bilalsha/sls-test-jest. Can you take a look. it do not work with test time out as well

Comment: Will look at it today

Comment: @BilalShah - Can you have a look at the answer now and see if it addresses your problem.

Comment: I tried the code on my machine with the above modififcations..it is working fine.

Comment: we need to add timeout I think because application do not start in time and test throws error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205931/discussion-between-ashish-modi-and-bilal-shah).